# SQL Query against Excel Spreadsheet

Tags: sql, vba, excel

I am facing a problem while firing SQL Query against Excel SpreadSheet. I have an Excel-2007 spreadsheet having around 1 lac rows with two columns. Column-1 (cid) & Column-2 (company). I would like to fetch all the rows from sheet(tab1) where company="spider". I am using below code. it's giving me results but only from first 1400 rows. If I do have company="spider" after 1400 rows it's not able to fetch it through below code. Need help for this.

```
Sub main()

On Error GoTo ErrHandler

Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
With cn
    .Provider = "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0"
      .ConnectionString = "Data Source=" & ThisWorkbook.FullName & "; Extended Properties=Excel 8.0"
    .Open
End With

Set ObjRes = cn.Execute("Select cid,company from [tab1$] where [company]= 'spider'")

result.Range("A:B").Clear
result.Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset ObjRes

cn.Close
Set cn = Nothing
Set ObjRes = Nothing

   Exit Sub
ErrHandler:
  cn.Close
  MsgBox "dataerror"

   End Sub
```

Please provide your valuable comments/solutions to fix this. Let me know incase you need any additional details.

Thanks.

Comment: which excel version is your datebase file? in other words- what is an extension of file from `ThisWorkbook.FullName`?

Comment: @kazjaw - The file is of Excel-2007.

Comment: try to change your `provider and connection string` according to [this information](http://www.connectionstrings.com/excel/)

Comment: @KazJaw - "Could not find installable ISAM" - I found this error message while using the connectionstring given by you. Any idea what went wrong. If possible could you please modify connection string in the above code given by me. It will really help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This worked for me on Excel 2007:

```
Sub sofMain20021767()

  Dim cn, ObjRes
  Dim result

  On Error GoTo ErrHandler

  Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
  With cn
    .ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" _
      & "; Data Source=" & ThisWorkbook.FullName _
      & "; Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Macro;HDR=YES"""
    .Open
  End With

'
  Set ObjRes = cn.Execute("SELECT cid,company FROM [tab1$] WHERE [company]= 'spider'")
'

' result.Range("A:B").Clear
' result.Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset ObjRes

  Range("D:E").Clear
  Range("D1").CopyFromRecordset ObjRes
  '
  cn.Close
  Set cn = Nothing
  Set ObjRes = Nothing

  Exit Sub
ErrHandler:
  MsgBox Err.Description
  Set cn = Nothing

End Sub
```

!!!Be careful, results are copied to Range("D:E"), erasing the old data of those 2 columns.

[image]

[image]

As shown, "spider" is found on record 2 and record 2838, ie > row 1400.

Extended Properties="Excel 12.0 Macro;HDR=YES" defines an Excel Document with Macro, ie a MyDoc.xlsm file, HDR=Yes indicates that the first row is the header, ie, column names.
For other format of Excel documents, please see [reference](http://www.connectionstrings.com/).

Or you can traverse the recordset:

```
  '
  '...
  '
  Range("D:E").Clear
  '
  'Range("D1").CopyFromRecordset ObjRes
  '

  '
  ' now we traverse the recordset:
  '
  Dim i
  i = 1
  '
  Do While (Not ObjRes.EOF)
    Range("D" & i).Value = ObjRes(0).Value
    Range("E" & i).Value = ObjRes(1).Value
    i = i + 1
    ObjRes.MoveNext
  Loop
  '
  '...
  '
```

Comment: Thanks a ton. Above code worked ! Just one quick question. Is there any limitation of the recordset in terms of maximum number of records it can hold ? Because when I tried to search one string that was occurring more than 1K time in the sheet, I got an error while copying the recordset results to sheet. Any idea ?

Comment: Only limited by Excel Rows, Recordset is unlimited for our practical usage. For error, you can try to use a do while loop to copy record/record?

Comment: Do you have any sample code that traverses through each record of a record set.I tried from myend but end up with nothing.